# Accessing an external site while hosting my site on an internal WAMP server

Tags: html

I'm creating a website hosted on an internal WAMP server.  I'm trying to link to an external site (even just something like Google) but it comes up with a 404 error because it's trying to find the external site in the directory of my site.  How do I link to an external site?  I've tried using a full address (i.e. https://www.google.com) but that doesn't work.

Comment: could you show the <a> tag code?

Comment: The browser will treat `href=google.com` as an address on your local server e.g. `http://www.example.com/google.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use:-

```
<a href='https://www.google.com/'>Google</a>
```

Comment: OH.  Slash at the end fixed it.  Thanks! @parvejalam

Comment: try to use in your html file and run that file in your local server

Comment: It's not because of the *slash at the end*, it's because of the `https://` at the beginning.

Comment: yes and in future if you want to use external links to your website then you should first open that link in the browser and copy the url and past it to href attribute